# Term for forwards/backwards phrase? (Not a palindrome)

Tags: phrases, phrase-order

My observation feels like it’s in the same realm but doesn’t quite fit under the spirit of the word-unit palindrome definition.

Is there a term for a phrase that swaps the first and last words to mean something different?

My specific example is “snake the drain” (using the snake tool to unclog a drain) and “drain the snake” (a man urinating)

Do any other similar phrases like this exist?

Comment: ... Man bites dog?

Comment: (1) "X the Y" & "Y the X" occurs when both X & Y are both nouns & verbs. (2) Check Spoonerism.

Answer (score 2):

**[Semantically Reversible Sentences](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2860570/)**

> The subject and the object of a reversible sentence may be reversed and still produce a meaningful sentence, whereas nonreversible sentences become semantically anomalous when they are reversed.

The addressed article shows that reversible sentences likely involve additional processing in the brain, compared to nonreversible sentences.